# Streaming microphone through sockets using socket IO and Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, socket.io, streaming

I am making an application where I want the user to use their mic (on their phone) and be able to talk to each other in the game lobby. However, this has proven to be more than difficult.

I am using Node JS socket io and socket io stream

on my client I am using the audio api to take my microphones input ( I am not really worried about this all that much because I am going to make this a Native IOS app)

```
    navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                     navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                     navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                     navigator.msGetUserMedia);

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
          navigator.getUserMedia (
            // constraints
          {
            video: false,
            audio: true
          },


    function(localMediaStream) {
        var video = document.querySelector('audio');
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
       lcm = localMediaStream;
       var audioContext = window.AudioContext;
       var context = new audioContext();
       var audioInput = context.createMediaStreamSource(localMediaStream);
       var bufferSize = 2048;
      // create a javascript node
      var recorder = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
      // specify the processing function
      recorder.onaudioprocess = recorderProcess;
      // connect stream to our recorder
      audioInput.connect(recorder);
      // connect our recorder to the previous destination
      recorder.connect(context.destination);
      },

  // errorCallback
  function(err) {
     console.log("The following error occured: " + err);
     $("video").remove();
     alert("@#");
          }
        );
            } else {
                 console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
            }

        function recorderProcess(e) {
            var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
            window.stream.write(convertFloat32ToInt16(left));
           //var f = $("#aud").attr("src");
           var src = window.URL.createObjectURL(lcm);
            ss(socket).emit('file', src, {size: src.size});
           ss.createBlobReadStream(src).pipe(window.stream);
          //ss.createReadStream(f).pipe(widnow.stream);

            }
         function convertFloat32ToInt16(buffer)
       {
            l = buffer.length;
            buf = new Int16Array(l);
            while (l--) {
               buf[l] = Math.min(1, buffer[l])*0x7FFF;
              }      
           return buf.buffer;
         }



             });

         ss(socket).on('back', function(stream, data) {

                //console.log(stream);

                var video = document.querySelector('audio');
              video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
              console.log("getting mic data");
            });
```

i which I can successfully listen to my self speak on the microphone. I am using the stream socket to create a blob to upload to my server...

```
        index.ss(socket).on('file', function(stream, data) {
                console.log("getting stream");
               var filename = index.path.basename(data.name);
             //var myfs = index.fs.createWriteStream(filename);

            var fileWriter = new index.wav.FileWriter('demo.wav', {
                channels: 1,
                sampleRate: 48000,
                bitDepth: 16
             });
          var streams = index.ss.createStream();
          streams.pipe(fileWriter);

        index.ss(socket).emit('back', fileWriter, {size: fileWriter.size});


        });
```

I cannot get the stream to write to a file or even a temporary buffer, and Then stream back to a client so I can then play or "stream" the audio real time. After a while the server crashes with saying that the pipe is not writable.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: can you play the created blob locally?

Comment: by usig : var src = window.URL.createObjectURL(lcm);  I am able to playback my mic. However I dont know if when socket io creates the blob if it is a correct blob file because it sends it to the server and I cannot find a way to retain it in my local client @dandavis

Comment: 2 things: 1, you could turn the blob into a dataURL and send that (with some reduced perf, but working is 100% faster than nothing). 2, you can use Chrome devtools network tab to monitor socket traffic, it's on the frames tab on the network tab's url list's item details page.

Comment: its transporting correctly. I know that for sure. My issue is I was wondering what would be the best way to solve this solutio as to how can I deliver audio data to clients across multiple platforms.I dont think data URLS is quite scalable if I have a lot of clients. this is also going tobe running concurrent with the actual game play to so I have to be effecient

Comment: dataURL would only add ~33% overhead. you should be able to emit a blob using socket.io. hybrids are possible: catch a dataURL in node, convert to a blob, and broadcast the blob. if the dataURL conversion or just bundling in general is slow, you can use a worker thread to keep your game loop smooth. try getting a real file local to node broadcasting as a blob to debug.

Comment: Actually a great idea, thanks for the advice @dandavis

Comment: @dandavis the blob url plays locally when i stream to server and back. Obviously though I'm not able to play it on any other devices . just the originator. do you know how I can transfer the actual data?

Comment: OMG, duh, how did i overlook that? you're sending a short string url, not blob data. only your machine has that windowURL... you should be able to emit _left_ (or whatever the actual blob is) and ignore the url until the blob comes back from socket.io, at which point you need a new url to listen to the blob. that said, i was getting tons of 2kb chunks with that script, so it might be hard to listen to that seemlessly.

Answer (score 1):

By using [SFMediaStream library](https://github.com/ScarletsFiction/SFMediaStream) you can socket.io and Nodejs server for live streaming your microphone from a browser. But this library still need some improvement before release to the production.

**For the presenter**

```
var mySocket = io("/", {transports:['websocket']});

// Set latency to 100ms (Equal with streamer)
var presenterMedia = new ScarletsMediaPresenter({
    audio:{
        channelCount:1,
        echoCancellation: false
    }
}, 100);

// Every new client streamer must receive this header buffer data
presenterMedia.onRecordingReady = function(packet){
    mySocket.emit('bufferHeader', packet);
}

// Send buffer to the server
presenterMedia.onBufferProcess = function(streamData){
    mySocket.emit('stream', streamData);
}

presenterMedia.startRecording();
```

**For the streamer**

```
var mySocket = io("/", {transports:['websocket']});

// Set latency to 100ms (Equal with presenter)
var audioStreamer = new ScarletsAudioBufferStreamer(100);
audioStreamer.playStream();

// Buffer header must be received first
mySocket.on('bufferHeader', function(packet){
    audioStreamer.setBufferHeader(packet);
});

// Receive buffer and play it
mySocket.on('stream', function(packet){
    // audioStreamer.realtimeBufferPlay(packet);
    audioStreamer.receiveBuffer(packet);
});

// Request buffer header
mySocket.emit('requestBufferHeader', '');
```

Or you can test it from your localhost with [this example](https://github.com/ScarletsFiction/SFMediaStream/tree/master/example/StreamingTest)

Comment: does that have a mobile version too? like with react-native?

Comment: Interesting.. I haven't tried react-native yet because my PC resources is limited, but it should support on WebView with Cordova.